# Is AssemblyTitle available in a WiX package?

Tags: .net, wix, .net-assembly

I'm creating a WiX installer for a WinForms application. The name of the application is going to change at some point in the next month or two, but I don't know what the new name will be and have no control over that. I have defined a string constant in the GUI layer of the application that contains the current name of the application, and have changed any code that used the product name to use this constant.

```
 Public Const PRODUCT_NAME As String = "My Funtimes Desktop Application"
```

I set the AssemblyTitle to use this constant.

```
<Assembly: AssemblyTitle(PRODUCT_NAME)>
```

Now, if possible, I'd like to reference the AssemblyTitle value in my wxs file, so that when I know the final name of the application, I only have to change it in one place. So something like:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="!(bind.assemblyTitle.FileIDOfGUIexe)" />
```

...but I can't seem to find anywhere obvious where this gets passed to the linker.

Is there a way I can access the AssemblyTitle of a .NET assembly in a WiX file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of assembly attributes that WiX reads is at http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html. AssemblyTitle isn't one of them but feel free to file a feature request at http://wixtoolset.org/issues/.

Comment: I would get the latest sources, add the attribute & rebuild the WiX - this is the most easiest & cleanest way. I presume adding that attribute itself should be trivial, as in 3-4 lines of code.

Comment: I would do that, but then other members of my team would have to also keep track of a custom WiX build for one small feature. I think it's easier to keep track of an extra variable, and do a feature request to let the WiX developers know about our use case.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty specific functionality, I doubt that WiX has something for this.

The bindings come from the file which are called `*.wxl (wix localization files)`. Visual studio automatically binds them through wix light. It generates one msi per localization file.  http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/build_a_localized_version.html

This can work, if you create a prebuild event/prebuild ms-task, which will read out the assemblyTitle attribute, and generate *.wxl file from it.

The other option is run dynamic XSLT over your wxs file, in also prebuild event.

There's also an option to run orca.exe after you have generated the msi(in post-build event), and let the orca change the ProductName.

Either way, I think you end up writing your own ms-build task/some kind of executable which can read the `AssemblyTitle`, and it will probably involve pre-build/post-build task.